# What is best command to collect many files into on location?

Tags: linux, debian, solaris

I have many files that I need to consolidate to one.
Is there a command that I can use to collect all my hosts file on different servers to one location.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a list of your servers, identical user to ssh with, you can do a simple script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `more my_servers.txt`
do
 scp $i:/etc/sudoers $i-sudoers
done
```

However, the default permissions of `/etc/sudoers` is 400, meaning only root can read it.

What I suggest next, and what I recommend, is a tool like Ansible. It works over ssh, and with a simple playbook you can collect all files you want. Requirements:

- install ansible
- set up inventory file with your servers listed there
- have ssh access and sudo account (because 400 permissions of sudoers)

You would then use the `fetch` module, like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: yoursshuser
  tasks:

    - name: fetch 
      fetch:
        src: /etc/sudoers
        dest: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}-sudoers
      become: yes
```

Use `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i yourinventoryfile` to run the playbook.

That's it.

Comment: thank you for your answer- what if I need to use puppet instead of Ansible, how would that work?

Comment: Any configuration management tool should do the work. Puppet, Chef, Ansible. I gave an example with Ansible because I consider myself fluent in it. I can't provide a similar example using Puppet or Chef.